# Configuring Struts 2 + Hibernate 5 + Spring 4 with annotations only (no XML)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to configure Spring 4 + Hibernate 5 + Struts 2 with java annotations (no xml at all, even web.xml)

I used spring configuration as below:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("net.iranet.isc.cm")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationContextConfig   {


@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    ....
}

@Autowired
@Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {

    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
    sessionBuilder.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect");
    .......
}
@Autowired
@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(
            sessionFactory);

    return transactionManager;
}
```

}

There is a GenericDaoImpl as

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Repository
public abstract class GenericDaoImpl<E, K extends Serializable> 
        implements GenericDao<E, K> {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Class<? extends E> daoType;


    public GenericDaoImpl() {
        Type t = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) t;
        daoType = (Class) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    protected Session currentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void add(E entity) {
        currentSession().save(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveOrUpdate(E entity) {
        currentSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(E entity) {
        currentSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(E entity) {
        currentSession().delete(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public E find(K key) {
        return (E) currentSession().get(daoType, key);
    }

    @Override
    public List<E> getAll() {
        return currentSession().createCriteria(daoType).list();
    }
}
```

Here is a sample DAO:

```
@Repository
public class ProductDAO extends GenericDaoImpl<Property, Integer> {

      public Product getAProductByName(String Name){
        //will be implemented later
        return null;          
      }

}
```

And finally the WebAppInitializer  ( instead of web.xml )

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(ApplicationContextConfig.class);

        ContextLoaderListener contextLoaderListener = new ContextLoaderListener(
                appContext);
        servletContext.addListener(contextLoaderListener);

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic openEntityManagerInViewFilter = servletContext.addFilter(
                "openEntityManagerInViewFilter", new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter());
        openEntityManagerInViewFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST),
                true, "/*");

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic strutsDispatcher = servletContext.addFilter(
                "strutsDispatcher", new StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter());
        strutsDispatcher.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST),
                true, "/*");    


    }

}
```

And the action

```
public class PublicPage extends ActionSupport {
    @Autowired
    private ProductDAO productDAO;
   //just for test will be set in service layer
   @Transactional 
   execute(){
    System.out.println( productDAO.getAll() );
```

I face the

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
```

I put some break points in `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` to see if this filter is working, and it worked!

Comment: You are using plain hibernate... SO adding a `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` isn't going to work, you need the `OpenSessionInViewFIlter` instead. Or drop the usage of plain hibernate and go for JPA instead.

Comment: Thanks ! worked for me, please send it as answer so I can mark it as correct. I appreciate if you could recommend what approach is better in your answer.

Comment: You don't have anything transaction related in your code... Annotate your service / repo with `@Transactional`.